# NLog Configuration Reload Event Not firing

Tags: c#, configuration, reload, nlog

I initialize NLog from a configuration and then add an extra target and rule via code. The target and rule should always be a part of the configuration where the config file may or may not change. I need on Configuration Reload for my method to be called that adds in my extra target and rule, however I cannot verify that the event is being fired.

I have tried adding my event handlers to both the LogManager and to the LogManager.LogFactory, have wired up both Reloaded and Changed (though I only need Reloaded). Called the LogManager.Configurtion = LogManager.Configuration.Reload() with a reconfigure of existing loggers but my event methods remain uncalled.

```
private static void ConfigurationReloadedHandler(object sender, LoggingConfigurationReloadedEventArgs args) { 
 System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Configuration was reloaded");
}

[Test]
public void WillCallReloadHandler() {
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Loading Config");
   LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nlog.config");
   LogManager.LogFactory.ConfigurationReloaded += ConfigurationReloadedHandler;
   LogManager.Configuration = LogManager.Configuration.Reload();
   LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
}
```

Expected result would be a  2 messages in my output window, one that says that the configuration was reloaded. Actual result is 1 message that says it is loading the config.

Answer (score 1):

`ConfigurationReloaded` is only called by NLog when detecting that the underlying `nlog.config` has been modified.

Instead you can do this:

```
LogManager.ConfigurationChanged += LogManager_ConfigurationChanged;

private static void LogManager_ConfigurationChanged(object sender, LoggingConfigurationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Configuration was changed");
}
```